# Cannot rename directories on samba share

Tags: samba, freerdp

I mounted a samba share on my machine by making an entry in fstab as :

```
//<IP of smb server>/<share name> /media/smb_share cifs user=<uname>,pass=<pass>,uid=<my uid>,gid=<my gid>,rw 0 0
```

and then  redirected the share via FreeRDP using the command :

```
xfreerdp /v:<IP of server> /u:<uname> /p:<pass> /d:<domain> -f /drive:<share name>,/media/smb_share
```

I'm able to copy data onto the share, edit files, save them, even delete them. I am able to rename an empty directory. While trying to rename a directory containing some files, I get :

```
An unexpected error is keeping you from renaming the folder. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem.
Error 0x80070091: The directory is not empty.
```

The output shows :

```
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in \\tsclient\<share name>\<directory>. Verify the item's location and try again.
```

The system prompts me to "Try Again" and when I click on "Try Again" it shows the same output repeatedly. 
[image]

[image]

I am, however, able to rename the directories by using an ICAClient. Has someone else encountered this issue? If so please post the solution or workaround for the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I guess you are not having the inherited permissions on the directories. what are the permissions of those directories? Can you share those ?

Comment: actually while redirecting i've put the entire share under read,write permission

Comment: try giving recursive permissions on the parent directory you are sharing.

Comment: If permissions were the issue, then same would have been the case with ICAClient but its working fine there. Infact, when i refresh, the folder gets renamed. Y d anomalous behavior?

Comment: Network latency would have caused that. Do you face any network latency ?

Comment: Network Latency might not be the issue after all, coz I'm able to rename files and empty folders without encountering any error. So its gotta be something else.

Comment: Please [edit] our question and show us your samba settings.

Comment: I even tried renaming using powershell but the outcome is still d same